# Remove Repeated Strings from String

Tags: string, algorithm

I wanted to try creating an algorithm to remove repeated strings in a string.

For example

Input: Hello
Output: Helo

Input: AAAAZZZZ5
Output: AZ5

Input: "Apples and Apples and Oranges"
Output: "Apples and Oranges"

I wrote the algorithm below ([JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/k2xl/WHqWb/))

```
function removeRepeat(str)
{
    var index = 0;
    var tempS = str.length;
    var currentBuffer = "";
    var repeatCharIndex = 1;
    console.log(str);
    for (var i = 1; i < tempS; i++)
    {
        var curChar = str[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            // check if duplicate
            if (str[j] === curChar)
            {
                console.log("duplicate detected at index ",j,str[j],"and index",i,str[i])
                // we have duplicate! means we could potentially have a repeated set of characters
                // i, j have same character, so let's move both forward
                var aheadLeft=j, aheadRight=i;
                var diff = Math.min(aheadRight-aheadLeft,tempS-aheadRight);
                var repeat = true;
                for (var num = 1; num < diff; num++)
                {
                    // we go backwards...
                    // ashiash ...
                    // we are at __h___h, so now we go
                    // _s__s_
                    console.log("\tis ",str[aheadRight+num],str[aheadLeft+num])
                    if (str[aheadRight+num] !== str[aheadLeft+num])
                    {
                        repeat = false;
                        break;
                    }    
                }
                if (repeat){
                    console.log("found repeat!",str,str[aheadLeft],aheadLeft,str[aheadRight],aheadRight);
                    str = str.substring(0,aheadRight)+str.substring(aheadRight+diff)
                    return removeRepeat(str);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}
console.log("New str: "+removeRepeat("nnnnnnnnzzzzzz1"));
```

The problem I'm having is that the algorithm doesn't produce the right result for `"Apples and Apples and Oranges"`

The repeated string should be `Apples and` and the result should be Apples and Oranges but I'm getting

```
Aples and Apples and Orang
```

I'm not sure how to fix my algorithm to check to see if the duplicate is part of a bigger picture. One idea I had was to go backwards rather than forwards through the string. Any ideas/tips would be great!

*Edit: I wasn't clear enough in my original examples.

Input `Hey Hi Hi Hi Hey Hi Hi Hi` should output `Hey Hi Hi Hi` rather than `Hey Hi` because the `Hi Hi Hi` , while repeating, is part of the larger `Hey Hi Hi Hi`

`Boots and Cats and Boots and Cats and YO` should equal `Boots and Cats Yo` not `Bots and Cats and Boots and Cats and YO`

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be `Aples and Oranges`?

Comment: "Apples and Apples and Oranges" the detected duplicate should be "Apples and."

Comment: Ah, so the requirement is to just detect the largest repeated units and throw away the duplicates? It still sounds a bit fuzzy so some additional details and examples might help.

Comment: As I understand it the result should be: `Aples and Orang`. You should probably think about/specify your requirements thoroughly before coding.

Comment: As @ZiyaoWei said, it should throw away the "largest" repeated duplicates.

Comment: @K2xL Your examples can't be the output of the same program.  Why wouldn't `AAAAZZZZ5` -> `AAZZ5` since `AA` and `ZZ` would be the largest duplicated strings?

Comment: Also, the largest repeated duplicate in `Hey Hi Hi Hi Hey Hi Hi Hi` is ` Hi`, since there's a space between `Hey Hi Hi Hi` and its duplicate.

Comment: @K2xL- in case of Hey hi hi example, you removed the longest same string. but in case of Boots and Cats example. i think answer should be Boots and Cats and Yo.

Or else. for Hey Hi case it should Hey Hi....

Can you please elaborate rule ?

Comment: i think it boils down to one pass or repeated passes (conceptually i mean, an implementation need not actually make multiple passes)

Comment: @AaronDufour The AAAAZZZZ5 turns to AZ5 because A is repeated 3 times. Actually, it's not about duplicates, it's about repeated strings.

Comment: But if you're choosing `A` as the repeated string, instead of `AA`, then its not actually the largest repeated string like you said before.

Answer (score 0):

what i suggest you do is write a function that removes the *longest* duplicate and then call it multiple times if you feel like it.  that's the simplest way i see of removing (much of) the ambiguity in your spec.

and if you want to do that, take the code you have, but instead of actually deleting code, simply track how much would be deleted, and where.  each time you find a way to delete more, update that info.

then, at the end, delete the largest found chunk (the info you have kept).

Answer (score 0):

This will do pretty close to what you're asking.  I think two of your examples require slight changes, but without those they don't seem to make sense.

In Javascript,

```
str.replace(/(.+?)(\1)+/g, function(match, group){return group;})
```

What we do here is match a string (group 1) followed by itself one or more times, and replace it with just one instance.  The group 1 match is non-greedy, so that `AAAA` -> `A` instead of `AA`.

Test cases:

```
1) "Apples and Apples and Oranges" -> "Apples and Oranges"
2) "Hey Hi Hi Hi Hey Hi Hi Hi" -> "Hey Hi Hey Hi"
3) "Hey Hi Hi Hi Hey Hi Hi Hi " -> "Hey Hi Hi Hi "
4) "Boots and Cats and Boots and Cats and YO" -> "Boots and Cats and YO"
5) "AAAAZZZZ5" -> "AZ5"
```

Note that 2) doesn't match the question, but it needs that space in order for the repetition you're looking for to actually be there.  I think 3) shows that it solves this case as you would expect.

Also, 4) doesn't quite match, but I think that is a typo in the question.